# Is there a way to accept a suggested, but rejected, edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Someone recently suggested an [edit to one of my posts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62819).

The suggested edit was rejected before I even saw it.

As the author of the post, I find the suggested edit correct, and I'd like to accept it despite the rejection from two community members.

Is there a way I, as the author, can accept the edit, even though it was rejected?

Obviously I can edit the post myself, but I think it'd be more fair to give credit where credit's due, and accept the contribution.

Comment: **No.** The edit was rejected correctly. The edit shows nothing but a function call, which DOESN"T contribute to your answer significantly. Here on CR.SE, we assume all users know  that basic thing. Also, users with rep < 1000 try to minor-aly edit the posts just to gain the rep.

Comment: The reason given for the rejection was, in both cases: *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer"* IMO, that's clearly incorrect, since the edit doesn't address me, but *does* make sense as an edit.

Comment: No, the rejection was correct. It didn't make sense as an edit because he should've conferred with you in the comments before pushing his opinion into your answer. You happen to agree with the comment, so feel free to make the edit yourself.

Comment: For the record, you didn't ask whether the rejection reasons were any good. That's why I haven't covered that in my answer. You asked whether it could be implemented anyway. It can.

Comment: Note that in the same respect, if an author rejects an edit, it's also removed from all the queues. I've accidentally rejected good edits before and it's rough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No.

Once an edit is rejected, it's removed from the review queue and can no longer be accepted.

Of-course, you can simply make the same edit yourself instead. You're the author of the post in question after all.